# кодировка на русском Zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, zipfile

Как задать русскую кодировку для разархивирования зиповского файла?а то когда разхивуется, получается какая-то белеберда

вот код

```
#Возвращаем имя без разряшения
    file_path = f'{file}'
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    index_of_dot = file_name.index('.')
    file_name_without_extension = file_name[:index_of_dot]
    print (file_name_without_extension)
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r')



    g = file_name_without_extension


    #каталог
    os.mkdir(f'{g}')
    patoolib.extract_archive(file,outdir=f'{g}')
    archive.close()
    #os.unlink(file)





    #искомый файл
    folder = []
    for i in os.walk(f'{g}'):
        folder.append(i)
        items = list(Path('.').rglob(n))

        # Если нашли папку
        if items:
            path = items[0]
            path.rename(path.parent / m)



    print('-Готово!')
    print('\n')
    dir_name = f'{file_name_without_extension}'
    output_filename= f'{g}'


    #архивация
    print('-Добавляем в архив')
    shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)


    print('-Готово!')

    #удаляем первоначальную папку для перпеиминования

    shutil.rmtree(f'{g}')


    print('-Удаляем ненужную папку, удачи!')
```

Comment: Что получается то при извлечении?

Comment: не русские символы

Comment: папки в архиве были с русскими символами, извлекаю в папку они на непонятном языке

Comment: У меня все извлекается и на русском, и на английском.

Comment: у меня всё равно непонятно какие символы